# цифровая клавиатура на телефоне при вводе в input type=“text”

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Как открыть цифровую клавиатуру на телефоне при вводе в поле `<input type="text" ...`? Нужно для ввода нескольких номеров телефонов

Comment: Разве она не сама открывается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день!
При помощи css свойства [appearance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) можно из поля number сделать абсолютно идентичное полю text. При этом разумеется на мобильниках будет открываться нумпад.

**Демо:** https://jsfiddle.net/w96k/8srhucp7/1/

```
<div>
  <input type='number'>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <input type='text'>
</div>

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Comment: с вводом - все отлично, но мне нужно также потом для корректировки  записать в числовое поле с таким стилем пару номеров телефонов через запятую, но не получается

Comment: Хм.. Сейчас посмотрю, что можно сделать. Вообще в качестве быстрого решения можно было бы написать скрипт, который бы при попытке ввода запятой, создавал бы второе инпут поле для следующего номера.

Comment: я тоже рассматривал похожий вариант, но, к сожалению, все усложняется ( input,output,edit ) ...

Comment: На самом деле мне кажется так даже выйдет проще, чем потом парсить эти номера. Ну ладно. Я сейчас обновлю демку с вариантом создания новых полей. По теме нашел статью: https://ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localization

В файрфоксе работает.

Comment: Возможно существует иной способ добиться отображения нумпада в андроиде.

Comment: И да, кажется он есть. input type tel, но там нужно парсить введенные символы через regexp.